# Pending Intent not launching

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have an activity that creates a notification.  The notification will launch the PendingIntent just fine when I use the and AVD emulator (targeting Android 2.1 update 1), but does not launch at all on an actual device (running Android 2.2.1).  Is there something fundamental that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

you have not posted any code. So I am sharing my code which worked for me:

```
public static void notifyIcon(Context context){

NotificationManager notifier = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.your_app_notification, "", System.currentTimeMillis());

/**
*Setting these flags will stop clearing your icon
*from the status bar if the user does clear all 
*notifications.
*/
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
    notification.contentView = contentView;

//If you want to open any activity on the click of the icon.

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "title", null, contentIntent);
    notifier.notify(1, notification);

//To cancel the icon ...
    notifier.cancel(1);

}
```

Here is custom_notification_layout.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="3dp" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: Don't forget to clear your app icon when appropriate If you set above flag.

Comment: if you leave the `notifier.cancel()` in the code, will notification show up at all?  My code is almost identical except my PendingIntent has a the `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` set and my Notification has the `FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` set.  And I do not cancel my NotificationManager

Comment: notifier.cancel(1); is used to remove the notification and if you don't want to remove then leave it...